If $(f_n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}} \to f$ in measure and $\int_{[0, 1]} f_n d\lambda \to \int_{[0, 1]} f d\lambda$, show the integral sequence holds for $E$
For $(f_n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathscr{L}^1([0, 1], \mathbb{B}_{[0, 1]}, \lambda)$, where $f_n \ge 0$, and $f \in \mathscr{L}^1([0, 1], \mathbb{B}_{[0, 1]}, \lambda)$, such that $(f_n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}} \to f$ in measure.
Show that if
$$\int_{[0, 1]} f_n d\lambda \to \int_{[0, 1]} f d\lambda$$
then
$$\int_{E} f_n d\lambda \to \int_{E} f d\lambda, \quad \forall E \in \mathbb{B}_{[0, 1]}$$
Since the Fatou's Lemma holds for a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $f_n \ge 0$ and $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \to f$ in measure, we have that
$$\int_{E} f d\lambda \le \inf \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} f_n d\lambda, \quad \forall E \in \mathbb{B}_{[0, 1]}$$
In the other hand, for $\epsilon > 0$, by hypothesis,
$$\Big| \int_{E} f_n  d\lambda - \int_{E} f d\lambda \Big| \le \Big| \int_{[0, 1]} f_n  d\lambda - \int_{[0, 1]} f d\lambda \Big| < \epsilon$$
which implies that
$$\sup \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} f_n d\lambda = \int_{E} f d\lambda$$
meaning that
$$\int_{E} f d\lambda = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} f_n d\lambda$$
My first question is, is this proof correctly? Secondly, apparently all the used results can be used for $(f_n: X \to [0, \infty))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$. So I don't clearly see why is $([0, 1], \mathbb{B}_{[0, 1]}, \lambda)$ required.

You can use Scheffe's Lemma to conclude that $f_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{1}}f$. After that, it follows that $|\int_{[0,1]}(f-f)\mathbf{1}{E},d\lambda|\leq ||f{n}-f||_{L^{1}}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$. Ofcourse, a small subsequential argument (extracting a further subsequence) is required to show that in the assumption of Scheffe's Lemma, it suffices to replace almost sure convergence with convergence in measure.

How did you get $$\left|\int_E f_n,\mathrm{d}\lambda-\int_E f,\mathrm{d}\lambda\right|\leq\left|\int_{[0,1]} f_n,\mathrm{d}\lambda-\int_{[0,1]} f,\mathrm{d}\lambda\right| \quad ?$$ Does this inequality hold if you consider $E=[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ together with $$f_n(x)=1+\frac{1}{n}\sin(2\pi x)\qquad\text{and}\qquad f(x)=1 \quad ?$$

@SangchulLee Yeah, I saw it is not true

Consider $f_{n_{k}}$ to be an arbitrary subsequence of $f_{n}$.
Then, $f_{n_{k}}$ converges in measure to $f$. Then, there exists a further subsequence such that $f_{n_{k_{l}}}\xrightarrow{a.e}f$. You also have that $$\int_{[0,1]}f_{n_{k_{l}}}\,d\lambda\xrightarrow{l\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]}f\,d\lambda$$.
By Scheffe's Lemma, this implies that $f_{n_{k_{l}}}\xrightarrow{L^{1}}f$.
Thus, we have shown that given any subsequence, there exists a further subsequence of $f_{n}$ such that it converges in $L^{1}$ to $f$. This is enough to say that $f_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{1}}f$.

In a metric space, a sequence $x_{n}$ converges to $x$ if and only if
for every subequence, there exists a further subsequence of $x_{n}$
which converges to $x$.

Now, for any $E\in\mathbb{B}_{[0,1]}$, you have that $$|\int_{[0,1]}(f_{n}-f)\mathbf{1}_{E}|\lambda \leq \int_{[0,1]}|f_{n}-f|\,d\lambda=||f_{n}-f||_{L^{1}}\to 0$$

Thank you very much mate! I could endly unfold all the reasonings and definitions to show the desired result!! Increadibly.

Thanks for your comment @BlueTomato. There are other ways to do it too. See here for example.

I see. After proving some details within your proof which I didn't know before, I could easily understand the second proof using the measure convergence. But let me know something, is it really required to use $[0, 1]$ and $\mathbb{B}_{[0, 1]}$? While proving those details I noticed that I didn't require that measure space, but for $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ works too. Even in the second proof, it is only required that the integral is finite, which holds since $f_n, f \in L^1$..?

@BlueTomato You are correct. Scheffe's Lemma holds for arbitrary measure spaces. Most exercises give you $[0,1]$ or $\Bbb{R}$ to let you feel a bit more comfortable in knowing that you are still within the domain of "real analysis". Ofcourse, $[0,1]$ has the distinction of being a probability space (the most important one) so it also serves as a means to let you familiarize with some results about probability theory.  So yeah, summing up, the proof I gave above, works for arbitrary measure spaces.

Very interesting perspective. Sometimes when someone is learning intermediate math requires some more attention to distinguish which queries are plausible and which ones are not. Thanks again.
